# Refresh p:dialog contents on click of p:commandButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

I need your help in refreshing the Dialog content on `commandButton` click as it is keeping the old values by default and it is not refreshing. My Code is:

```
<h:form id="Requests">

    <p:dataTable id="PendingRequests" var="hr" value="#{hrd.pendingRequests}">
        <p:commandButton id="submitbutton" update=":Requests:#{hr.dialogueName} "
                oncomplete="PF('#{hr.certificateDialogue}').show()">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{hr}" target="#{hrd.selectedRequest}"/>
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:dialog id="cert1" header="cert1" widgetVar="cert1" modal="true" showEffect="fade"
            hideEffect="fade" resizable="true">
        <p:outputPanel id="SS1" style="text-align:center;" autoUpdate="true">
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>

    <p:dialog id="cert2" header="cert2" widgetVar="cert2" modal="true" showEffect="fade"
            hideEffect="fade" resizable="true">
        <p:outputPanel id="SS2" style="text-align:center;" autoUpdate="true">
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

Comment: Your commandbutton is not calling any action and you dialogs do not contain any dynamic content. Please create an mcve

Comment: @Kukeltje In the setter setSelectedRequest in the bean, I am checking the value of the column type, if it is type = "A", then call method1() else called method2()

Comment: Do not do business logic in getters or setters. Do it in event (listener) methods. Even then, a MCVE would still be helpful as there are a bunch of variables here whose values are completely unclear.

Comment: @BalusC I did the business logic in the setter because I was not able to pass the selected row variables in my dataTable to the Dialog once I clicked on the commandButton View Dialog which is in the same row. So is there any alternative way to refresh the Dialog contents other than using the Update=":Requests:dialogName"? Currently it is keeping the old values... Also, Do you think that the problem is from that part?